# Getting values out of view model structs

Tags: ios, swift

I'm pretty new to swift. Currently, I'm attempting to create a view screen programmatically in Swift 4. The screen is supposed to have a number of images and textlabels. I created a view model with a struct of several declared images and strings.

The struct setup thats in my view model:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

struct ShareUIModel {

    let heroImage: UIImage
    let secondHeroImage: UIImage
    let longHeroText: String
    let shortHeroText: String

}

extension ShareUIModel {

    static func testObject() -> ShareUIModel {
        let heroImageImage = placeholderImage
        let secondHeroImageImage = placeholderImage
        let longHeroTextText = "long words"
        let shortHeroTextText = "short words"
        return ShareUIModel(heroImage: heroImageImage, secondHeroImageImage: secondHeroImage, longHeroText: longHeroTextText, shortHeroText: shortHeroTextText)
    }
}
```

**Question**: How can I create an instance of ShareUIModel in a view controller and access the values?

Comment: Well.. you would need a UIView subclass that's designed to interpret `ShareUIModel`. Do you have one made? If so, update your code. Otherwise, I'll post a generic approach to this.

Comment: @murphyguy I don't have a UIView to interpret it, the most I have in the view controller is the container.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally, you can apply a MVM object to it's view in many ways. Personnaly, I recommend either a `convenience` initializer, or a custom variable with what's called a `didSet` value observer. Didset observers are called when their parameters are applied, without modifying the stored value.

So given a uivew subclass that can handle your model :

```
class ShareUIView : UIView {


    var model : ShareUIModel? {
        didSet {
            guard let mode = model else { return }
            applyModel(mode)
        }
    }

    let heroImage = UIImageView()
    let secondHeroImage = UIImageView()
    let longHeroLabel = UILabel()
    let shortHeroLabel = UILabel()

    //Initializer
    convenience init(model: ShareUIModel) {
        self.init()
        self.addSubview(heroImage)
        self.addSubview(secondHeroImage)
        self.addSubview(longHeroLabel)
        self.addSubview(shortHeroLabel)
        self.model = model
    }

    private func applyModel(_ model: ShareUIModel) {
        self.heroImage.image = model.heroImage
        self.secondHeroImage.image = model.heroImage
        self.longHeroLabel.text = model.longHeroText
        self.shortHeroLabel.text = model.shortHeroText
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        buildYourComponents()
    }

    func buildYourComponents() {
        //This will be called whenever ShareUIView's size or layout is applied.
        //code to build out your labels and imageViews
    }

}
```

So from here, you can either apply it onto your `UIViewController`'s `view` by initializing it:

```
class Controller : UIViewController {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let shareview = ShareUIView(model: ShareUIModel.testObject())
        view.addSubview(shareview)
        shareview.frame = //whatever you want here..
    }

}
```

This method means you have to set the size afterwards.

Or, you can build out the ShareView first, then apply the model object afterwards (say, from a user's selection, or from a network task) by applying the model onto `ShareView`'s model parameter. This requires you to have a strong reference to it however, as in initializing it into your Controller class:

```
class Controller : UIViewController {

    var shareView : ShareUIView = { //Initialized as a parameter of Controller instead
        var v = ShareUIView()
        return v
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(shareView) //You add the view
        shareView.frame = .zero//you build the view - .zero is just an example here.
    }

    func applyTheModelFromWherever() {
        shareView.model = ShareUIModel.testObject() //you apply the model object.
    }

}
```

From this you should have ample examples to get creative with how to update a MVVM view with it's model object content. You would then also create methods to clear the content, dismiss it etc, depending on the use-case of the view itself.

Comment: As a personnal rule of thumb, make sure you actually store the model in the UIView subclass somehow. Especially in forms, or editable content since it makes it easier to track changes, or to push changes to your delegates etc.

Comment: Thank you for the response, it was more than I was expecting.